# How can area under ROC (AUC) be bad when precision, recall, and accuracy are all good?

Tags: classification, auc, precision-recall

I have a model with the following scores:

Precision: 0.703588
Recall: 0.976526
Accuracy: 0.694936

I thought this was fairly decent, especially considering that my (binary) response class is 1/3 of the data. But then I have an AUC of 0.53, which is barely better than a coin toss. How do I reconcile the above scores with this AUC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrangling the numbers, I get the following as percentages of the dataset:
TP≈0.685037 FP≈0.288597 FN≈0.0164671 TN≈0.00989861

(So it seems you've swapped the positive class.  That's not important for the ROC analysis, but it makes wording the next paragraph difficult.)

The point is that your accuracy and precision aren't really great.  Since your "positive" class makes up ~30% of your data, your baseline accuracy is already 70%.  Your model's high recall (on the majority "negative" class?) just indicates that it does a good job at capturing the majority class, but you're making quite a few false positive predictions.

To be more concrete, your hard classifier has a high false positive rate, ≈0.9668, landing it at the point (0.9668, 0.9765) in ROC space, which doesn't guarantee much about a high AUC: assuming your model performs randomly on the two intervals of thresholds split by this point, so that the ROC is two straight lines connecting at this point, you'd have an area of only 0.505.

Comment: You're right. Part of my confusion came from the fact that I had inadvertently swapped the classes. Thanks for the help!